# hello there! i have issue with the hostinger platform on adding the product to cart

Tags: wordpress, web, woocommerce, hosting

so i have created an website using hostinger (*wordpress and woocommerce*). the problem is i am not able to add the service (*pricing table*) which i am providing as an product and i am not able to direct it to the cart. the cart page has already been set up with the checkout page.
i have **tried** adding the cart's link into the service's add to cart button, still no result and i have tried adding the service as an product and it got me no where. could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The pricing table won't redirect to the Cart or Checkout by default. You need to add a correct link that would redirect to the cart or checkout on the pricing plan's button itself.

Check [Cart Flow](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cartflows/) plugin. I used it recently and made that after choosing a plan from Pricing Table, it goes straight to the checkout with the product added. The fewer clicks your client will make, the better experience he will have.
And this is the [video on how to do that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgkHGBiCQqE).

If you are not so tech-savvy, I would recommend you to check on Fiverr. There are a lot of people that can help with your WordPress and Hostinger services.